# fogging up glasses on shabbos

Tags: shabbat

Is there a problem of nolad while blowing on your glasses to clean them, the air you 'huh' onto your glasses condenses to a fog, which לכאורה should be no different than freezing water which is also just condensing it into ice?

Comment: Is there a problem of breathing when it is cold?

Comment: I have seen a poseik do so on Shabbos, but never discussed it with him.

Comment: @wfb -- you breathe to live, so it's OK.  You don't clean your glasses to live, so the question is legit.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi so must one avoid going outdoors to prevent breathing in the cold?

Comment: @wfb-- No.  Inside or out you are breathing for the purpose of living, not for another practical use of your breath.

Comment: breathing cold air would at the very worst be a מתעסק